# Package not found from vcs repo

Tags: composer-php

I have forked a repo and created a branch called 3.0 that I would like to install to my project to test (not a longterm fork. I want to create a pull request after testing). I have added the following to my composer file:

```
"repositories": [{
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/albertski/laravel-grid"
}],
```

When running `composer show "albertski/laravel-grid"` I get `Package albertski/laravel-grid not found`.

When I run `composer require albertski/laravel-grid:3
.0-dev` I get the following:

```
Could not find a matching version of package albertski/laravel-grid. Check
  the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is avail
  able in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

Am I missing any steps?  According to the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) that should be it. I am using Composer version 1.9.0.

This is my full composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/browser-kit-testing": "^5.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/albertski/laravel-grid"
    }],
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": ["tests/utilities/functions.php"]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Just to test it out I created a branch called `3.0_albert` and updated the composer.json name field to `"name": "albertski/laravel-grid",`.  (Not a fan of doing this because I eventually want to perform a pull request)

Then ran `composer require albertski/laravel-grid:3.0_albert-dev` but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Instead of calling:

```
composer require albertski/laravel-grid:3.0.x-dev
```

You call:

```
composer require leantony/laravel-grid:3.0.x-dev
```

Basically by adding:

```
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/albertski/laravel-grid"
}],
```

You are telling composer to check your repo first for the package instead of the default one.